# OracleText: search a word in html file

Tags: oracle-text

I've created 2 file HTML:
CiaoMondo.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <title>Ciao Mondo!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Oracle Text provides indexing elements for creating Oracle  Text indexes and for specifying indexing preferences. This chapter describes the indexing elements that you can use to create an Oracle Text index.</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

and CiaoOracle.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <title>Ciao Oracle!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>La Mare Jonio lascia il punto di fonda ed entra nel porto di
        Lampedusa dove la Guardia di finanza notifica il provvedimento di sequestro. I migranti sbarcano tutti. Poi il comandante, Pietro Marrone, viene convocato d'urgenza dalle fiemme gialle di Lampedusa. Marrone si é recato in caserma accompagnato dall'armatore Beppe Caccia e dal deputato di Sinistra italiana Erasmo Palazzotto. A quanto si apprende i militari dovrebbero notificare al comandante un atto.
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I've imported (or I try it) in an Oracle's table in the following mode:
[Oracle's instuction](https://pastebin.com/ja5EwadD)
Now, I would like search a word in H1's tag of these two file (eg: Jonio).
I executed these instructions:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), id 
from htmlprova
WHERE CONTAINS(docs, 'Jonio within H1') > 0
order by score(1) desc;
```

but

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
SELECT SCORE(1), id
from htmlprova
WHERE CONTAINS(docs, 'Jonio within H1') > 0
order by score(1) desc
Error at Command Line:1 Column:7
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-29908: missing primary invocation for ancillary operator
29908. 00000 -  "missing primary invocation for ancillary operator"
*Cause:    The primary invocation corresponding to an ancillary operator
           is missing.
*Action:   Add the primary invocation with the same label as the
           ancillary operator.
```

How can I solved?

Answer (score 0):

Please reference the [CONTAINS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/csql.htm#i997503) syntax. When using the [SCORE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/csql.htm#CCREF0107) operator, you need to specify the `label`.

For your query, add a `1` directly after text search string:

`WHERE CONTAINS(docs, 'Jonio within H1',1) > 0`

That should resolve the `SQL Error: ORA-29908`.